# Vectors in C++ : Why i'm getting so much errors for this simple copy & print program?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, iteration

i'm trying to use algorithm lib & vector lib to first copy a set of numbers from an array into a vector then printing it using iteration, where is the problem of my code?

and one thing is that i chose 2 way to do this iteration first using vec.begin() ; vec.end() method & the other one is for (i = 0 ; i < vec.capacity() ; i++)
both facing errors.

what should i do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int intArray[] = {5,6,8,3,40,36,98,29,75};

    vector<int> vecList(9);
    //vector<int>::iterator it;
    copy (intArray, intArray+9,vecList);
    //for(it  = vecList.begin() ; it != vecList.end() ; it++)
    for (int it = 0 ; it < vecList.capacity() ; it++)
    {
        cout<<*it<<endl;
     }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: hint: What is `*it` when `it` is of type `int`? The two methods are different approach of how to access an element.

Comment: well i removed it, u're right but still a lot of those fuzzy messy errors, which doesn't mean anything to me...

Comment: `std::copy` needs an iterator for the third argument too.

Comment: This [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) documentation has an example very close to your own.

Answer (score 7):

There are several improvements possible.

You confuse iterators with indices. An iterator `it` is a glorified pointer into the vector, that you need to derefence by typing `*it`. An index `i` is an offset from the beginning of the vector and saying `vecList[i]` will give you that element.

The initialization of the vector is best done using initializer lists (C++11), rather than reading from an array.

You need to loop to `vecList.size()`. The capacity of the vector is the size of the allocated storage space for the elements of the vector container. Looping is best done with a ranged-for loop as shown by `Kerrek SB`, or a `std::for_each` + a lambda expression, or a regular for loop as you did. In that case however, it's best to get into the habit of doing `it != vecList.end()` (instead of using `<`) and doing `++it` instead of `it++`.

Note that I also used `auto` to avoid writing the explicit iterator type. It's also a good habit to get into using `auto` wherever you can.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // initialize vector with a list of elements
    vector<int> vecList {5,6,8,3,40,36,98,29,75}; 

    // loop from begin() to end() of vector, doing ++it instead of it++ 
    for (auto it = vecList.begin(); it != vecList.end(); ++it) 
    {
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }

    // the pause command is better done by setting a breakpoint in a debugger

    return 0;

}
```

Output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/74jIj) (this uses the g++ 4.5.1 compiler, it's best to upgrade to at least that version to take advantage of C++11 features).

Comment: There's **a lot** more problems with the code. He's attempting to dereference an `int`, he's not initializing the index...

Comment: @user1602447 As you can see from the output on Ideone, this code compiles on g++ 4.5.1 and later. If you are serious about learning C++, then it's best to upgrade to at least that (and preferably to the latest 4.7.1) version.

Comment: I don't agree to using `auto` wherever you can. I use it when it removes unnecessary clutter.

Comment: as i compile it these are the errors i get, and here's another question i'm using backtrack 5 r3 released 2 days ago it shoul have the latest version, nevermind, this one is using Qt C++ Plain text Project, it's The Latest version What about it?

Comment: @FredOverflow Herb Sutter and Scott Meyers disagree with you.

Comment: yes, read the first line in the errors: you need to compile with `-std=c++0x`

Comment: GUYS...Hey please, What The Hell Should I Do...?
It's Making Me More Confused Than OK-to_go...

Comment: @rhalbersma : well how? using Qt i donno how...!

Comment: @user1602447 If you want to know how to configure QtCreator to using different compile flags, please search this site for answers, or ask a  new question about it.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're confusing indexes and iterators.

#### w/ index:

```
 for (int i = 0  ; i < vecList.size() ; it++)
 {
    cout<<vecList[i]<<endl;
 }
```

#### w/ iterators

```
 for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = vecList.begin()  ; i != vecList.end() ; it++)
 {
    cout<<*it<<endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A. you need to iterate on `vecList.size()` not `vecList.capacity()` which mean how much memory the vector is reserving for himself (not how much of it is in use).
B. you tried to use the integer index `it` as an iterator with the call to `*it`, you should check Luchian Grigore answer for the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, but I wanted to show how modern C++ allows you to do away with lots of the brittle dependencies on details:

```
int intArray[] = {5,6,8,3,40,36,98,29,75};

std::vector<int> vecList(std::begin(intArray), std::end(intArray));

for (int i : vecList) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
```

Using iterators and algorithms idiomatically, you can often remove any explicit mention of details such as lengths of arrays, thus making your code more robust.

Comment: You're using C++11 anyway, so why not combine the first two lines? `std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3};` Technically in this case, even `for (int i : {1, 2, 3}) std::cout << i << '\n';` is possible.

Comment: @chris How about `for (int i : {1, 2, 3}) std::cout << i << '\n';`? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Typo mistake use :     copy (intArray, intArray+9,vecList.begin());

so,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main()

{

int intArray[] = {5,6,8,3,40,36,98,29,75};

vector<int> vecList(9);
vector<int>:: iterator it;
copy (intArray, intArray+9,vecList.begin());
for (it=vecList.begin();it!=vecList.end(); it++)
{
    cout<<*it<<endl;
 }

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```